# Mysql Distinct Join of records not matching or do not have join data at all

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I have two tables: Authors and Posts. Authors can have several Posts (1:N).

```
Authors:
- id
- name

Posts:
- id
- authors_id
- post_type
```

I need to retrieve all Authors where their post_type is not of a certain type, lets say "Type1", which would need by logic to include Authors without posts at all.

I currently try this:

```
Select DISTINCT a.*
from authors a
LEFT JOIN posts p  ON p.authors_id = a.id 
WHERE 
p.post_type <> 'TYPE1' 
OR p.authors_id IS NULL
```

This will return correctly all authors which have:

```
- no posts at all
- or have only posts not of TYPE1
- and will not show authors having only posts of TYPE1
```

BUT: It will return also those authors who have TYPE1 plus any other type of post.

Is this possible in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ought to work:

```
Select DISTINCT a.*
from authors a
LEFT JOIN posts p  ON p.authors_id = a.id 
WHERE 
a.id NOT IN (SELECT p.authors_id from authors a INNER JOIN posts p ON p.authors_id = a.id  WHERE p.post_type = 'TYPE1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change you query a bit by getting the grouping first and then joining to it

```
Select DISTINCT a.*
from authors a
LEFT JOIN 
(
select authors_id, group_concat(post_type order by post_type) as post_list
from posts
group by authors_id
having post_list not like 'TYPE1%'
) tab ON tab.authors_id = a.id 
WHERE tab.authors_id IS NULL
```